# TVP - are they used for input and output?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've started to read the notes on Table Value Parameters

- [HERE ON MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)
- [HERE ON SOMMARSKOG](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html#TVP_in_TSQL)

Can these TVPs be used as input parameters and output parameters?
Is there a point in having them as an output parameter?
I get the feeling it might be possible to have a TVP as output from one stored procedure and then that feeding into another stored procedure - possible?
The syntax of the script which calls the first sproc and then calls the second sproc using the output TVP from the first is the bit I'm unsure of.

**EDIT**

Apologies for the confusion of my post - it seems that the initial procedures results need to go into the TVP - I thought that the TVP needed to be involved *within* that sproc. So a model of what I was talking about is the following - hopefully a valid use of TVPs...

```
CREATE TYPE myfirstTVP AS TABLE (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

GO --<<this sproc will find the ids (+ other fields) that need to be investigated
    CREATE PROC test1 as
        SELECT 1 UNION 
        SELECT 2 UNION
        SELECT 3;
GO

GO --<<this sproc uses the found ids to do one aspect of the investigation
    CREATE PROC test2 
    @t2 myfirstTVP READONLY 
    AS
            SELECT id*2 
            FROM @t2;
GO

GO --<<this sproc uses the found ids to do another aspect of the investigation
    CREATE PROC test3 
    @t4 myfirstTVP READONLY 
    AS
            SELECT id*3 
            FROM @t4;
GO    

    --<<this is where the TVP is used and the sprocs are called 
    DECLARE @t3 myfirstTVP ;
    INSERT INTO @t3 
    EXEC test1;

    EXEC test2 @t3;
    EXEC test3 @t3;
```

Comment: You can pass a TVP along to a second stored procedure, but keep in mind that TVPs are read only, so it's not like you could do anything to it in the current procedure before passing it along. As for output parameters, not sure, could you explain the potential use case?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Hello. I have 5 sprocs. The first sproc I run will produce a table that is 5 fields wide and maybe 20 rows - I was thinking this could be an OUTPUT TVP. This TVP is then used by all the other 4 sprocs as an input paramter. Possible?

Comment: I still don't understand where the output has any bearing. If you pass a TVP to one stored procedure, then need to pass it to another, just pass it directly as input. The first stored procedure can't change it, so what value does pulling it out again add?

Comment: the first sproc can't change it? the structure of it? the data in it? you can insert into a TVP once and that is it? I want the first sproc to put data into the TVP the other sprocs only need to read it

Comment: You can populate the TVP and then pass it into the other procedures directly. You can't pass a TVP into a stored procedure and then change it or insert more data. The key word you seem to be missing: `READONLY`

Comment: @AaronBertrand ok maybe I'd be better looking [HERE](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)

Comment: @AaronBertrand That's it - I only want to use populate it _once_ ...the other sprocs only read from it.

Comment: So create the TVP in the main and populate it, then pass it into the other procedures. You don't need to do that inside a sub-proc, do you?

Comment: I'm trying to set up an example but with two sprocs similar to @a1ex07 example below ; will add to the OP

Comment: @AaronBertrand ok - clicked now; it's a structure that exists on the server like a # table - so no need to have it as an OUTPUT - the other sproc will be aware of it once it is created? Cool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you want to achieve, but you can in a sense emulate behaviour of 'output' parameters ,

```
CREATE TYPE LIST_OF_INT AS TABLE (id int not null primary key);
GO
create procedure test1 as
begin
  declare @t1 LIST_OF_INT;
  insert into @t1 (id) values (1);
  select * from @t1;
end;

GO

declare @t2 LIST_OF_INT ;
insert into @t2 
EXEC test1;

select * from @t2;
```

Comment: let me play with your example and try to set up a model of what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed this bit from the MSDN link you cited.

> Table-valued parameters must be passed as input READONLY parameters to
>   Transact-SQL routines.

Comment: ok - bit of a vague question; I'll only add inforation to the TVP once; then I will feed it into 4 or 5 other stored procedures - possible?

Comment: @whytheq I can't visualize the code you're talking about - did you try it?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'll add code to OP - seems like the TVP is needed in thr first sproc

Comment: +1 as this is probably one of the most important properties of TVPs